# tethering via multiple smartphones

Tags: wireless-networking, router, tethering

I would like to allow several people to combine their individual data plan available on their smartphones, to provide a large internet access point via Wifi.

So, it would basically be like using your smartphone to create a wifi hotspot allowing access to the internet (tethering), but by combining several smartphones bandwidth, have a broader bandwidth offering.

Is such thing doable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the [Connectify utilities](http://www.connectify.me/homepage-b-2/)?

It will merge several networks and distribute the traffic among them to create a faster connection. I tried it a few years ago when it was still in beta. I combined 2 wifi networks, my mobile data plan via USB tether, and a PowerLine ethernet connection.

The speed increase wasn't huge but it was easy to set up and use. It provides a lot of useful, real-time data for each connection so you will be able to tell right away whether or not it is actually providing you a speed increase.